# PWM Controller for known f(t)

Tags: pwm, control, simulink

Suppose I have some signal input which I know.
The signal is 85 seconds long and its not something I can describe with equation but It looks as follows:

[image]

Now, I have made a simple PWN controller that basically compares between the input (this signal) and some repeating sequence signal and whenever it is small it should return 1 to activate and whenever it is larger it should return 0:

[image]

However, Inside this repeating sequence signal block there is a need to define the time values and output values to define the signal.

My question is how do I know what amplitude I had like the repeated sequence to be?

Since if I set the triangle tip at amplitude higher than my whole input signal it means that the PWM will be mostly OFF and if I set the amplitude lower than my signal than it would give ON signals.

Thank you.

Comment: Normally one uses a Linear Predictive filter to track the variance of error expected and then provide feedback to reduce (variance). If the integrated accumulated squared error is within tolerance after tracking within expected tolerances to the predicted input, then a Lock status or an Autocorrelation result may be computed to indicate locked to good signal.  SNR from random noise or process. Do you have a window tolerance and output spec? Don't think about PWM yet,.

Comment: The only thing I have as given is that I would like to obtain as output the closest signal to the input which means that I know the Minimum/Maximum values I had like my signal to be if I understand correct.

Comment: all you want is a simple Analog to PWM converter ?? define ranges in spec for In and out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum value minus the minimum value of the repeated sequence signal block should be equal to the maximum value minus the minimum value of the input signal.

Your input signal ranges from 0 to about -0.13.
In your diagram, the repeated sequence signal block is a triangular waveform.
So, the amplitude of the triangular waveform should be about 0.13 / 2 = 0.065.

If you set the amplitude lower than 0.065, the PWM signal will 'clip' and you will lose information.
If you set the amplitude higher, you lose accuracy, because you use less than the maximum 100% PWM to represent the input signal.

Still, setting it to 0.064 would yield results that look quite similar to the PWM signal with the triangular amplitude of 0.065 and it shouldn't be mostly ON. Same for setting it to 0.066, it shouldn't be not mostly OFF.